# Why do some entries generate a template error on get next or previous post when others do not?

Tags: templating, error-message

I have setup chevrons to links to the previous and next posts.  It seems to work for all but a handful of posts.  Those posts generate the following template error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a null variable

```
        <p class="post-meta">
            {% set prev = entry.getPrev( 'posts' ) %}
            {% set next = entry.getNext( 'posts' ) %}

        <!-- previous post -->
        <span><a href="{{ prev.url }}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
        <!--date of post -->
        <span>{{ entry.postDate | date('F d, Y') }} </span> 
        <!-- next post -->
        <span><a href="{{ next.url }}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
    </p>
```

The specific line the template error references is

`<span><a href="{{ prev.url }}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>`

There are previous entries to access.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First – you're passing a string value (`'posts'`) to the [`getNext()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNext) and [`getPrev()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getPrev) methods, which will produce unreliable results.

The `getNext()` and `getPrev()` methods actually expect either an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) instance, or an object representing an ElementCriteriaModel's attributes (i.e. a query like `{ section: 'posts' }` – not a string, number or any other, non-iterable value.

I'm guessing `'posts'` is a section handle, but Craft won't know that and it will just ignore the string and *return any element matching the current element's type* - so if you call `entry.getNext('posts')`, you're probably going to get an entry back, but it won't reliably be an entry from the `'posts'` section; it could be an entry from *any* section in your system.

So here's how your code probably should look:

```
{% set criteria = { section: 'posts' } %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}
{% set next = entry.getNext(criteria) %}
...
```

If this code is in an entry template, you could even do something like this:

```
{% set criteria = { section: entry.section } %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}
...
```

An additional tidbit: The only instance where it's ok to call `getNext()` and `getPrev()` without passing an ECM (or pass an invalid value, like a string), is whenever your `entry` variable is already part of an element result set – for instance, whenever you're looping on the result of a `craft.entries` query:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('posts') %}
    ...
    {% set next = entry.getNext() %}
    {% if next %}
        <a href="{{ next.url }}">{{ next.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As for the error message you're seeing:

The `getNext()` and `getPrev()` methods should always be wrapped in a conditional, because *they won't realibly, always return an element* (i.e., there might not *be* a "next" or "previous" entry in your current context):

```
{% set prev = entry.getNext(criteria) %}
{% set next = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}

{% if prev %}
    <a href="{{ prev.url }}">{{ prev.title }}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    <a href="{{ next.url }}">{{ next.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

The error message you're getting, is simply stating that there is no `url` attribute for one of your `next` or `prev` variables – meaning that those variables don't actually refer to valid elements, because the `getNext()` and/or `getPrev()` methods returned a NULL value. Simply wrap your code in conditionals, and the error will go away.

If you want to make sure that you're always displaying both a "next" and a "previous" link, you can make the links "loop" by having them point to the *first* and *last* entries respectively, whenever there isn't a next or previous entry in the set:

```
{% set criteria = craft.entries.section('posts') %}
...
{% set next = entry.getNext(criteria) ?? criteria.first() %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(criteria) ?? criteria.last() %} 
...
{% if next %}
    <a href="{{ next.url )}">{{ next.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate 
This is the standard craft reference what I use all the time. If you use this it will work!

Comment: This is for a single entry, not a page of entries.

Comment: And it also did not work